# how to get data from a solana transaction message

Tags: web3.js, transactions, metadata

I want to access the data of a transaction , for example I want to be able to access the metadata of this token. How do I go about it
[image]
Right now this is what I'm using to get the transaction message

```
let tx=await connection.getTransaction("5swq5xq6fDMvdo8N3dHWLiTMbR73Qps18BuVrDbuNoWS6PQjtPHcr2Tzv1sBE7hzcnMwNk6aH3MzZG6HWXqv6TdY")
console.log("here", tx?.transaction?.message)
```

Which gets me this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transaction message does not give you the account contents, only the account pubkeys and instruction data involved. The metadata information is stored in one of those accounts, and you'll have to fetch it separately.

In your case, if you want to get the metadata for a token account, you'll need to find the metadata account, by looking through the `instructions`, pulling out the index, getting the pubkey from `accountKeys`, calling `connection.getAccountInfo` on the correct pubkey, and finally deserializing that account.